Which SendKey to use on Conditional basis
I am using SendKeys commands for some automation purposes as below :
$filePath = "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test\Test.pbix" 

Start-Process $filePath 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 15 

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%') 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('F')

Occasionally in some scenarios, post the Start-Process query, the below sign in window pops up thereby leading to failure.

So I had below queries which I could not find any help with in MSFt docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN
How to identify whether this window has popped up for an IF else case scenario
What is the send key command to click on Cancel to close the sign in window
Note: I tried System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ESC}') but it didnt work.
